# Using Puppeteer, how do you get text from an <h1> tag?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I'm using CucumberJS & Puppeteer. I am having a difficult time extracting the text from an `<h1>` tag.

The ember .hbs code is:

```
<div class="grid__cell" data-test-foobar4="true">
    <h1 class="ao-headline u-font--light" data-test-foobar3="true">{{pageTitle}}</h1>
</div>
```

I'm using HTML `data-` tags for my selectors since EmberJS uses dynamic id's.

```
// Read page table title
async verifyTestTileForList() {
    const textContent = await this.page.evaluate(() => document.body.querySelector('[data-test-foobar3="true"]').textContent);
    console.log('Page title = ' + textContent);
}
```

When I run this, I get:

> Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null

Which doesn't make sense to me. I look at the HTML, and I see:

```
<h1 data-test-foobar3="true" class="ao-headline u-font--light">Imports</h1>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 8):

The element is most likely being generated dynamically, so you should wait for the element with [`page.waitForSelector()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options) before attempting to scrape the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent):

```
await page.waitForSelector('[data-test-foobar3="true"]');
const textContent = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('[data-test-foobar3="true"]').textContent);
console.log('Page title = ' + textContent);
```

Comment: You were correct - I had tp put a waitForSelector().  As a rule of thumb, for dynamic (in my case emberJS components that use the {{ }}) I need to put a wait or the code will attempt to look for it when it has not been rendered yet.